# How to create a idendity for each id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Is it possible to create a composite key in sql 2000

```
code    id
abc      1
abc      2
abc      3
def      1
def      2
ghi      1
```

where the id restarts the count at each change of code. I need the numbering to be exactly like that either by creating a table or other SELECT statement trickery.

how to do this in sql server 2000

Need Query Help

Comment: Are there any other columns in the table, or is this it? What is the highest number of repeat values for `code` you should expect? And are you trying to update an existing table or put this information into a new table?

Comment: @Aaron, nothing i just entering the data in to the table through form.

Comment: And do you really need to *store* this data in the table? Would it not make more sense to query it at runtime, so that you don't have to recalculate the numbers for the entire table every time you update, insert or delete a row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to retrieve this data at runtime, without having to actually store it in the table, which is incredibly cumbersome to try and maintain. I'm using a #temp table here but you can pretend `#a` is your permanent table. As is, this will support up to 256 duplicates. If you need more, it can be adjusted.

```
CREATE TABLE #a(code VARCHAR(32));

INSERT #a SELECT 'abc'
UNION ALL SELECT 'abc'
UNION ALL SELECT 'abc'
UNION ALL SELECT 'def'
UNION ALL SELECT 'def'
UNION ALL SELECT 'ghi';
GO

SELECT x.code, id = y.number FROM 
(
  SELECT code, maxid = COUNT(*) FROM #a GROUP BY code
) AS x
CROSS JOIN 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT number FROM master..spt_values
  WHERE number BETWEEN 1 AND 256
) AS y
WHERE x.maxid >= y.number;

DROP TABLE #a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (code, id) VALUES( 'code',
(Select ISNULL(MAX(id), 0) FROM TableName where code = 'code')+1)
```